How to replicate the dynamic stdout of a command?
I am working on a Raspberry Pi OS, and I make this Python script to run a command and capture it's output. It works fine for commands that outputs text in a sequential way. But when I try to run commands that use dynamic updates, like apt-get update that display a progres percentage, it fails to capture it. Dow you know how can I do to replicate the exact display behavior of the command, like it is shown in a real terminal window ? The thing is that I don't realy use print(line.strip()), instead I send the data over a network socket on another computer, and there I display it. On the other computer I know how to print the data in the virtual terminal windows, but what I don't know is how can I read the control characters(?) and how I interpret them... ? I dont' need it to work with complex programs with menus or other stuff, just simple commands like that shows some progress like apt-get update does...
import subprocess
import select
import os

os.environ['PYTHONUNBUFFERED'] = '1'

process = subprocess.Popen(['apt-get', 'update'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, universal_newlines=True)

while True:
    line = process.stdout.readline()
    if not line: break
    print(line.strip())

process.wait()

Update1:
I made another python script that prints a number and then moves the cursor in the same position and prints again over...
import time

for i in range(10):
  print(i)
  print('\033[F', end='')
  time.sleep(1)

And then, when I run that script as a subprocess an read it's output in raw byte mode, I get those escape charaters I sent... But if I try with apt-get update command I receive only text and not the escape characters for moving the cursor to display in the same location the package readin progres.
import subprocess
import select
import os

os.environ['PYTHONUNBUFFERED'] = '1'
process = subprocess.Popen(['python3', 'cursor.py'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

while True:
  ready = select.select([process.stdout], [], [], 0.1)[0]
  if not ready: continue
  B = process.stdout.read(1)
  if len(B) < 1: break
  print(hex(B[0]))

process.wait()


On one hand, you can read character-by-character rather than line-by-line, but that's not good enough in the general case, because programs often look at whether their output is going direct to a terminal (vs to a different program) and have different/fancier output intended for human readers vs consumption by other software. If apt-get uses isatty() to look at whether its stdout and stderr goes to a terminal or not, there's no guarantee that you'll get the same content when you run it as a subprocess with stdout=subprocess.PIPE even if you're relaying that content in real time.

That said, you shouldn't be trying to read or interpret control characters at all -- just make sure the remote terminal's TERM variable is reflected in the environment of the subprocess, so the process knows which terminal type to use control characters for, and let the remote terminal your client is using be responsible for rendering. And if the problem is that it's not sending the "pretty" output you want when there's no terminal attached, we do have existing, already-answered Q&A in our knowledgebase that talks about setting up a pseudoterminal.

(If your client is using a web interface rather than a traditional terminal, there are still javascript terminal emulators available, so you just need to make sure you have a TTY emulated and set the TERM variable in the subprocess to reflect whichever specific type of terminal that javascript terminal emulator is emulating).

I set the TERM to "dumb" for plain text, and when I run sudo apt-get update it still use control characters...

Which control characters, specifically? (If you're just talking about \r, for example, that's not terminal-specific so TERM doesn't control it).

I mean the escape sequences, like \033[F for moving the cursor. But I read the stdin in raw byte mode and it seems there is noting sent, just text.

I'd want to see the details -- the specific control sequences and the context in which they're seen. In general I wouldn't expect apt-get to send those with TERM=dumb. Granted, if it's not apt-get itself but the pre- or post-install scripts for a package it's installing, all bets are off -- packaging is often sloppy.

If it is indeed not apt-get itself but dpkg-reconfigure invoked by apt-get that's sending these sequences, then maybe you want to set DEBIAN_FRONTEND=readline. But we really need detailed context before we can figure out exactly what's at fault.

apt-get is just an example... I want that my virtual terminal to handle the escape sequences, like \033[F for moving the cursor with all programs... I don't know how to explain better... I don't have much experience with pipes and I don't really understand things well... I update the question. Please open it.

If you want a virtual terminal to handle escape sequences, use a terminal that understands escape sequences on the display end. See for example https://xtermjs.org/

The display end is on an Windows laptop in a Delphi application. I want the terminal to be integrated in my application, not to be separated. And that's what I'm trying to do, to build a virtual terminal that understand the cursor movement escape characters.

That's a much larger question than fits our format -- very much in the "if you can imagine a book that answers your question, you're asking too much" category (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

BTW, Google finds an attempted terminal emulator written in Pascal @ https://github.com/maerlyn/old-delphi-codes/blob/master/_KOMPONENSEK/ics/Delphi/Vc32/EmulVT.pas

You don't understand... I just need to make a python script that execute a command and read it's output in real time as it is displayed in the terminal. Everything else I already know how to do it...

The linked duplicate's code using select() will get you the "read in real time" part. If that's all you need the duplicate already covers it. The cursor movements &c is a separate matter to handle client-side by having the client/display layer implement a proper terminal emulator.
